# How to limit choices in Input.ChoiceSet of Adaptive Cards?

Tags: adaptive-cards

How can we apply limit on Input.ChoiceSet for choosing the option in adaptive cards?

I want to apply limit for choosing the options in input.choiceset in adaptive crads. i want to make that People can choose only any of 2 option.

this is my json:

```
{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.4",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
            "choices": [
                {
                    "title": "Choice 1",
                    "value": "Choice 1"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Choice 2",
                    "value": "Choice 2"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Choice 3",
                    "value": "Choice 3"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Choice 4",
                    "value": "Choice 4"
                }
            ],
            "placeholder": "Placeholder text",
            "id": "ab",
            "isMultiSelect": true,
        }
    ]
}
```

[this is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ3Ut.png)

Comment: Hi Sagar. Excuse me but, as English is not my native language, I encounter a translation issue. Do you need that the user can select 2 and only 2 of the four choices? Not more, not less? It would be a mix between a radio group and a checkbox group, maybe not very easy to understand for the end-user. Are you sure there is not logic to combine the four choices by two, in order to propose 2 radio groups?